# Show that if $a$ and $b$ are positive integers then $(a, b) = (a + b, [a, b])$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Show that if $a$ and $b$ are positive integers then $(a, b)=(a + b, [a, b])$.

I was thinking that since $[a, b]=LCM(a, b)=\frac{ab}{(a, b)}$ that if $d= (a + b, [a, b])$, then $d|[a,b]$ and thus $d|(a, b)$ since $(a, b)|[a, b]$

Then I would just have to prove that $(a+b, (a, b)) = (a, b)$.

Is that the right way to go?

Comment: Why $d|[a,b] \land (a,b)|[a,b] \Rightarrow d|(a,b)$?

Comment: I don't quite understand if this is a hint or a question

Comment: That is a question.

Answer (score 5):

Another  way :  Let $(a,b)=d$ and $\displaystyle \frac aA=\frac bB=d\implies (A,B)=1$

So, $\displaystyle(a+b, [a,b])=(d(A+B), dAB)=d(A+B,AB)$

Now, if $D$ divides both $ A+B, AB; D$ will divide $A(A+B)-AB=A^2$ and $D$ will divide $B(A+B)-AB=B^2$

$\displaystyle\implies D$ will divide $(A^2,B^2)=(A,B)^2=1\implies D=1$

Comment: Downvoter, what is wrong here?

Comment: nice answer(+1)

Comment: Nice and elegant. Didn't have to use the FTA or prime factorization either.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the direction $(a, b) \mid (a+b, [a,b])$ poses no problem.

For the reverse divisibility, set $d = (a, b)$ and let $x, y \in \mathbb Z$ with $ax+ by = d$. Then for all $n \in \mathbb Z$,
$$(a+b)\left( x + n\frac{b}d\right) + b \left(y-x - n\frac{a+b}d\right) = d$$
We choose $n$ such that the second term in the LHS is divisible by $a$, and we will have a linear combination of $a+b$ and $[a,b]$ that equals $d$. Take $n = y(y-x)$. We have
$$1 - y\frac{a+b}d = \frac ad (x-y)$$
Multiplying both sides by $y-x$ and plugging this in gives
$$(a+b)\left( x + y(y-x)\frac{b}d\right) + b \frac ad (x-y)(y-x) = d$$
as desired.